# Java Adding Characters to Map depending on if they exist already

Tags: java, syntax

I am doing an assignment for school, which requires me to write an algorithm that places a key (of character type, in this case) and a value that has been incremented by 1 and then placed back into the map, as an incremented value. 
If the current character doesn't exist however, I am supposed to place the key-value pair of 'current_character, 1'. This method simply adds a new entry to the map and does not increment the value (assuming it's the first of its kind).
Here is the code:

```
 private void calculateCharCountAlpha(){
    for(String current : lines){
        for(int i = 0, length = current.length(); i < length; i++){ // iterate through each character of each string
            char currentKey = current.charAt(i);

            if(! (charCountAlpha.containsKey( currentKey )) ){ // check if the map doesn't contain the current character at the current location in the current string
                charCountAlpha.put( currentKey, 1 ); // place the current character into the map, with a value of 1
            } // end of if
            else{
                int val = charCountAlpha.get( currentKey );
                val++; // add 1 to val
                charCountAlpha.put( currentKey, val ); // place the current character in the map, with a value that has been added to 1
            } // end of else
        } // end of for
    } // end of for-each

    /** Call calculateCharCountDescendingByCount */
    calculateCharCountDescendingByCount();

} // end of calculateCharCountAlpha()
```

Here is charCountAlpha:

```
 private TreeMap< Character, Integer > charCountAlpha = new TreeMap<>(); // this map stores the number of words, with their counts. Also stores the elements in order of key
```

Honestly, my biggest question here is, "Does this properly add elements to the map?". I have been debugging for a little bit, and have not be able to see the issue of why my output is so strange. I can attach my output, but I would also have to include quite a bit more code to make sense of what it happening, so I figured (since this is my main problem), I would just include this code.

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: If you're not sure, you could try printing the map and seeing if it looks correct.  I think your code is OK.  If you have problems figuring out why the output is wrong, please post a different question and include that part of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works correctly, though you could simplify:

```
int val = charCountAlpha.get( currentKey );
val++; // add 1 to val
charCountAlpha.put( currentKey, val );
```

with:

```
charCountAlpha.put( currentKey, charCountAlpha.get(currentKey)+1);
```

Also, there is probably no need to use `TreeMap` if you have a known key set (like for example English alphabet), you could use `HashMap` instead to get better time complexity.